# IKImageView get image frame

Tags: c#, cocoa, frame, imagekit, ikimageview

I can change position of Image inside IKImageview and also I change image, when next button is clicked , but postion of Image is reseted.... I need to get information about old position of the Image , but haven't found any solution yet.

Here is code of how I'm trying to change image:

```
RightImage.SetImageWithURL (NSUrl.FromFilename (_rightImagePath));
```

RightImage view is outlet from **storyboard** file

```
[Outlet]
        ImageKit.IKImageView RightImage { get; set; }
```

for example I have loaded the picture and then changed position of it with mouse movement :[image]

after this I've just changed image (with url - code is above), and position of image was reseted to the default one :  [image]

So, my question is, how to get information about **Image** **frame or coordinates** inside IKImageView ?  Or how to change image without changing it position ?